# how send file using dataform from ionic angular app to laravel server?

Tags: angular, laravel, ionic4

i'am trying to send file formdata from ionic-angular to laravel server with consuming api REST of course , Then i prepare enverything in the ionic as you see in the code bellow but i haven't the solution to get file in laravel controller .
Code ionic

```
onFileSelect(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.uploadForm.get('profile').setValue(file);
      console.log(file);
    }
  }
  onSubmit() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.uploadForm.get('profile').value);
    console.log(this.uploadForm.get('profile').value);
    this.complaint.AddFile(this.uploadForm.get('profile').value).then((result)=>{
      console.log(result)
      alert(result);
    },(err)=>{
      console.log("insert err: "+ err)
      console.log("this.myInfo: "+ JSON.stringify(this.myRec))
      //alert(err);
      this.uploadText ="error .....";
    })
  }

 AddFile(file) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              const formData = new FormData();
               formData.append('file', file);
              console.log(formData);
              let   value =    localStorage.getItem('token')
                     let headers = new Headers();
                     headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
                     headers.append('Accept','application/json');
                     headers.append('Content-type','application/json');
                     headers.append('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
                      headers.append('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
                 headers.append('Authorization','Bearer '+value);
                   this.http.post('http://192.168.1.14:8000/api/complainfileionic',formData,{headers: headers})
                   .map(res=>res.json())
                   .subscribe(data => {
                       resolve(data);
              }, (err) => {
                       reject(err);
        
                   });
                    });
                  }

Laravek function in controller
```

public function complaintsfileionic(Request $request){

```
    $target_path = "uploads/";
     
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
     
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $data = ['success' => true, 'message' => 'Upload and move success'];
        echo json_encode( $data );
    } else{
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $data = ['success' => false, 'message' => 'There was an error uploading the file, please try again!'];
        echo json_encode( $data );
    }
}
```

Comment: pretty sure you can't have content type both application/json and multipart/form-data so remove the ../json header. what error are you getting ? Have you tested sending the file to api from tools like Postman or Insomnia ? did it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning!

First sorry my English, I hope you can understand in ionic v4.
You must implement the library `@angular/common/http`
In the view I did something like this

```
    <ion-button color="primaria" shape="round" >
      <span>Cadastrar documentos</span>
      <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" (change)="uploadFile($event.target.files)" />
    </ion-button>
    <ion-progress-bar [value]="progress.percentage"></ion-progress-bar>
```

In view Ts

```
async uploadFile(event: FileList) {
this.progress.percentage = 0;
this.arquivosService.pushFileToStorage(event.item(0))
.subscribe(event => {
  console.log('pushFileToStorage event! ', event);
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
    this.progress.percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
  } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
  }
});
this.selectedFiles = undefined;
```

}

and in my service `this.arquivosService';

```
  import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http'


   constructor(
     private storage: AngularFireStorage,
     private util: UtilService,
     private http: HttpClient,
     public storageService: StorageService,
    ) {
    this.baseUrl = environment.baseURL;
    }



  pushFileToStorage(file: File):Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
   const accessToken = this.storageService.getToken()
   const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
   'x-access-token': accessToken });
   const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
   formdata.append('file', file);
   const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'https://127.0.0.1:4002/api/file/upload', 
    formdata, {
    headers: headers,
    reportProgress: true,
    responseType: 'text'
   });
   return this.http.request(req);
}
```

in my case as i used an intercept it was necessary to put a header i believe that if you don't use it it is not necessary.
If I was useful for you, rate me, rate me as positive